# ActiveRecord validating scoped associations before saving the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I'm writing an API, and have two models that will be created as part of one post, those being `Order` and `LineItem`.  My API is expecting (ideally) data in this format:

```
{
    "name": "Test Name",
    "date": "2013/01/01",
    "items": [{
        "name": "Item One",
        "quantity": 10
    }, {
        "name": "Item Two",
        "quantity": 30
    }]
}
```

In the example above, "name" and "date" are properties of my `Order` model, and each entry in the "items" array is a `LineItem`.  My two models are defined as follows:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order

    validates :name, :uniqueness => {:scope => :order_id }
end
```

So each line item must be unique to the order.  When I get this POST request to build my items, it seems that I can't properly validate the uniqueness of the `LineItems` until **after** saving my `Order`.  However, if my `LineItem`s fail to validate, then I have saved an order that I don't want in my system.

What's the proper way to handle situations like this?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you're looking for is asking line items to be validated when Order.valid? is called. You can do this with validates_associated:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items
  validates_associated :line_items
end
```

This will cause the validations on line items to be called too. For more details see:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, it seems that a currently open bug prevents the validation from failing (although the duplicate line_item would not be saved to disk). See:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8308
- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4568

In order to get around this bug you probably want to create a before_validation callback to validate name uniqueness for new items. Once the bug is fixed you'd be able to remove this callback.

Comment: But will this work with the scoped validation?  To ensure the uniqueness of the lineitems scoped to the Order, Rails will generate a SELECT based on the order.id to ensure no records in the DB violate the validation.  This causes problems, as the order doesn't yet have an ID.  is this incorrect?

Comment: Correct and it seems like there are some open bugs wrt to not checking the objects in memory. The above will stop duplicates from being saved but will not fail validation. I'll edit to point this out.